# SQL Server geography and spatial functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial, sqlgeography

I have a table containing a series of records of rectangular areas on the earths surface that are of interest to me.

I store these in a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas]
(
    [AreaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [north] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [south] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [east] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
    [west] [decimal](9, 6) NULL
)
```

I would like start doing some spatial queries so I need to convert those limiting latitudes and longitudes into geography fields, and was considering the following

```
[PointGeo] [geography] NULL,
[LineGeo] [geography] NULL,
[PolyGeo] [geography] NULL
```

With PointGeo, I need to create a lat/long for the corner of each box.
With LineGeo, I probably need to join the points together in sequence, adding a duplicate of the first point to close the box. The lines would be used for display purposes mainly.

With PolyGeo I need to use the same LineGeo nodes to create polygons

I can create a simple point geometry from Lat/Long values using something like

```
UPDATE dbo.<table>
SET PointGeo = geography::Point(Latitude,Longitude,4326)
```

I cant see how to add multiple points or lines/polys other than using ...fromWKT... functions which looks like a huge amount of text manipulation, e.g. the 4 boundary points would require something like

```
UPDATE dbo.<table>
SET PointGeo = geography::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOINT((' + CAST(lat1 AS varchar(8)) + ' ' + CAST(long1 AS varchar(9)) + ' ), (' + CAST(lat2 AS varchar(8)) + ' ' + CAST(long2 AS varchar(9)) + ' ))', 4326)
```

and it gets more complicated the more nodes added, counting quotemarks and brackets to ensure they are all present in the correct order.

Am I missing some simple functions to create multipoint geographies from lat/long co-ordinates?

Would it be possible to write T-SQL recursive wrapper functions to do this?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything - WKT is the way to go for a general solution. Though there are various aggregate functions that you could use for special cases. Like, instead of explicitly creating a MULTIPOINT WKT, you could create a series of single Points using `Point()` and then using `CollectionAggregate()` over the set.

Comment: Also, take a look at `CONCAT()` for a less burdensome way to do string concatenation.